# Ruby regex that matches unless escaped with \

Tags: ruby, regex, lookbehind

To identify things like:

```
[stack][overflow]
or
[is great!]
```

I do:

```
/\[([^\]]+)\](\[([^\]]+)\])?/.match(s)
```

Now I want to extend this such that if `[...][...]` or `[...]` comes after `\` it won't be recognized:

```
\[stack][overflow]   # => Should not match
\[is great!]         # => Should not match
a \[b][c] \[d] [e]   # => Should match [e]
```

How could I extend the regex to achieve this ?

It should work both in Ruby 1.9.2 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: do you want all the [...] behind a \ not to be recognized?

Comment: @Chris: Only 1 or 2 `[...]` that are following immediately after `\`. I added one more example to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this regexp:

```
/([^\\\[\]]|^)\[([^\]]+)\](\[([^\]]+)\])?/
```

You can try it here:

http://rubular.com/r/L796M2pcG7

Hope that helps.

EDIT: reacted to your comment
EDIT: next one

Answer (score 3):

You can do this instead:

```
/(^|[^\\\]])(\\\\)*(\[([^\]]+)\]){1,2}/
```

(added `(^|[^\\])(\\\\)*`)

This works by matching either the start of the subject string (in case there is nothing before `[`), or any character except `\`, followed by any number of escaped `\\`.

```
[1]       => yes
[1][2]    => yes
x[1]      => yes
x[1][2]   => yes
\[1]      => no
\[1][2]   => no
\\[1]     => yes
\\[1][2]  => yes
\\\[1]    => no
\\\\[1]   => yes
\\\\\[1]  => no
\\\\\\[1] => yes    
...
```

Try it here: http://rubular.com/r/ST9qOVjUXe

Comment: `/(^|[^\\])\[([^\]]+)\](\[([^\]]+)\])?/.match("\\[a][b]")` should not match

Comment: your_regex.match('\\[a][b]') should not match

Comment: it matches the [b] only; I guess it works if you add `]` in `[^\\]`